# refresh google map every x minutes in webbrowser in xe5

Tags: delphi, google-maps-api-3, delphi-xe5, twebbrowser

i am develop a small mobile application in XE5 using delphi, i will show the current location in google map in webbrowser. the problem is how to refresh the google map every x minutes in webbrowser. the default refresh time is 20 second. thanks.

Comment: Use TTimer on the form and refresh the webbrowser every X time.

Comment: how to link the ttimer to webbrowser?I use the swithch to activate the location sensor then,display google map in webbrowser

Answer (score 1):

Use TTimer to refresh.
You can change the X minutes in the property Interval.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  self.WebBrowser1.Navigate('www.embarcadero.com');
  self.Timer1.Interval:= 10000;
  self.Timer1.Enabled:= True;
end;

procedure TForm1.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  self.WebBrowser1.Refresh;
end;
```

Comment: But i donot have the refresh function in my xe5!

Comment: @WuKai Your attempt to post your code in a comment obviously did not succeed. To expand on a question please **edit** the question.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are navigating with something like

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate('https://www.google.com/maps/@<latitude>,<longitude>,<zoom>z');
```

and you want to update the map because the location has changed.
In this case there's no point in calling something like refresh (on TWebBrowser for Windows, or similar on TWebBrowser for mobile), since that would just use the same coordinates as before.

Instead, at the timer event, get your updated location and then simply navigate as above with the new coordinates.

---

**Edit after new info**

Right now I can not verify with a real LocationSensor so I assume that the LocationSensor and the request for the initial map works in the OnLocationChanged event. Note also that depending on installed technology in your device, the location sensor may need quite some time to be ready to report location changes.

You attempt to initialize (set interval and enable) the timer in the OnLocationChanged event, (except that now those lines are outcommented). Thus starting the timer depends of course on this event to fire. If you have verified that the OnLocationChanged event fires then this is OK, just take away the comment markers.

However, if initially, the OnLocationChanged event doesn't fire, then you need to start the timer somewhere else. When you drop a TTimer on a form, it is by default enabled and has an interval of 1000 ms. So you could just change the interval to 5 minutes (300 000 ms) at design time and the timer will start at program startup.

On the other hand, you may want to show the (or a) google map immediately in which case you could use the OnShow event of the form, using a previously saved (or default) location until the LocationSensor starts to report location changes.

```
// Instead of having this constant in several procedures,
// place it for example in the private section of your form
const
  LGoogleMapsURL: String = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=%s,%s&';
var
  SavedLocation: TLocationCoord2D;
....
procedure TTabbedForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // using a previously saved location
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(Format(LGoogleMapsURL,
    [SavedLocation.Latitude.ToString, SavedLocation.Longitude.ToString]));

  // remove these lines if timer is enabled at design time
  Timer1.Interval := 300000;
  Timer1.Enabled  := true;
end;
```

You don't need to repeatedly set the timer interval and enabled properties in the OnTimer event

```
procedure TTabbedForm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
const
  LGoogleMapsURL: String = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=%s,%s&';
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(Format(LGoogleMapsURL,[Locationsensor1.Sensor.Latitude.ToString,LocationSensor1.Sensor.Longitude.ToString ]));
// you can remove these two lines
//  Timer1.Interval:=50000;
//  Timer1.Enabled:=true;
end;
```

If this doesn't answer your question, you need to be more specific in **how** you want it to work and **what** precisly is not as you want.

---

**Edit 2**

Next time you really need to describe all aspects of your problem.

The OnLocationChanged event is an event of LocationSensor1. The easiest way to get rid of it is to remove from LocationSesnor1LocationChanged any const and var declaration as well as  the code between begin and end. Then just do a build and the IDE will remove all traces of it.

Comment: but if i use the LocationSensor to show the map,then

Comment: @WuKai Edit your question and add the code you are using to show the map initially.

Comment: @ Tom Brunberg                                                                            thanks for your answer                                                                                   but the google map is still refresh every 20 seconds (by default). i can not find the OnLocationChanged event in the event column of TTimer; I think the OnLocationChanged event is not fired by TTimer and i donot know where to fire it;

Comment: @WuKai Did you see my latest edit `EDIT 2`? Are there still some open issues?

Answer (score 0):

@ Tom Brunberg
I use the Locationsensor LocationChange to display the google map in WebBrowser,below is the code:

```
    procedure TTabbedForm.LocationSensor1LocationChanged(Sender: TObject;
  const OldLocation, NewLocation: TLocationCoord2D); 
 const
  LGoogleMapsURL: String = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=%s,%s&';

begin

  ListBoxItem3.Text := 'Latitude: ' + NewLocation.Latitude.ToString;
  ListBoxItem2.Text := 'Longitude: ' + NewLocation.Longitude.ToString;
  Locationsensor1.Distance:=200;
  { and track the location via Google Maps }
  WebBrowser1.Navigate(Format(LGoogleMapsURL, [NewLocation.Latitude.ToString, NewLocation.Longitude.ToString]));

//  Timer1.Interval:=50000;
//  Timer1.Enabled:=true;

  ClientModule1.ServerMethods19Client.insertParcelLocation(EDIT4.Text,now,NewLocation.Longitude,NewLocation.Latitude);
```

i want to refresh the google map in webBrowser every 5 minutes.Thus, i use the TTimer. but i do not know where to raise Timer event? the code below is i try to raise the timer event in webBrowser, but it did not work!

```
    procedure TTabbedForm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
const
  LGoogleMapsURL: String = 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q=%s,%s&';
begin
    WebBrowser1.Navigate(Format(LGoogleMapsURL,[Locationsensor1.Sensor.Latitude.ToString,LocationSensor1.Sensor.Longitude.ToString ]));
     Timer1.Interval:=50000;
     Timer1.Enabled:=true;
    end;
```

Comment: For future reference, note the **edit** button under your original post. That lets you edit your original post, instead of posting additional info in an answer to your own question. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Wu Kai: Set Timer1.Enabled:=true; on start of your form or after you set the url.